# Error after changing sails model

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm quite new to sails, and I don't seem to find the actual pieces of knowledge I need to change a model.
I have created an api and then changes the attributes in the model as seen on some tutorials. When I `sails lift` I get the following error:

```
info: Starting app...

/Users/me/myapi/api/models/Menu.js:14
    dateTest:{
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
```

I guess this means that the model doesn't accept the edited Menu.js

Whats needs to be done to get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably forgot a comma `,` after the previous attribute.

```
anAttribute: {
  ...
}, // Here

dateTest:{
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks - and shame on me... I've just installed a js linter on Atom